# Differentiating between Twilio Gather Timeout and Empty Input

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

We are trying to gather caller information through a series of `<Gather>` steps, but give them the option to escape from the flow by sending just `#`.  We would like the caller to be able to escape the series of `<Gather>` steps and follow separate logic if a step times out. According to the [`<Gather>` documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action), in the example below the `<Redirect>` verb will be used by Twilio in either case if the input times out or if the caller sends no input and just hits `#`.

```
<Response>
  <Gather action="https://localhost:8001/api/Step" method="POST" timeout="7" finishOnKey="#">
    <Play>[Prompts omitted]</Play>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect method="POST">https://localhost:8001/api/Step?timeout=true</Redirect>
</Response>
```

My question is, is there any way to differentiate between those two scenarios? The major complication is this: Our existing recorded prompts already instruct callers to use # as both the escape key and finishOnKey, so if possible we need to keep those the same.

Comment: Do the other potential responses to the prompts require multiple key presses?

Comment: @philnash Yes, they do. I got a potential answer from someone in the Twilio community forums. If their answer works, I'll update this question with the solution. It requires getting the `FinishedOnKey` from the request form (which for some reason isn't an available member of the C# VoiceRequest model provided in the Twilio.AspNet.Common package).

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for the TwiML gather verb, I see this called out:

> Note: finishOnKey only works when a digit sequence precedes it. It
> cannot be used as a mechanism to stop a Gather without previous
> digit input

Are you seeing different behavior? It sounds like you are attempting to press # without any input.